# Content not displaying when using full screen button

Tags: html, css, fullscreen

I am developing a website and I would like one of the sections to have a button that will expand it to fullscreen without using the fullscreen API, so it'll just enlarge the section basically over all the other elements. I would also like it to have an animation like for when it expands and retracts back to normal. I've tried multiple approaches but everytime I do it, the content in my section doesn't appear. [The section I want to have enlarge with a button is where it shows the operator and the whole border around that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3Jsu.png)

Here is my code:

main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet1.css">
    <title>eFocusCNC-Web</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function toggleDropdown(spanElement) {
            $(spanElement).next(".dropdown-menu").slideToggle();
        }

        document.getElementById('fullscreen-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
            var wrapper = document.querySelector('.right-section-wrapper');
            wrapper.classList.toggle('fullscreen');
        });




</script>

    <style>
        body {
            animation: fadeIn 0.5s ease-in forwards;
            animation: fade 0.35s ease-in-out forwards;
            box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px grey;
        }





        @keyframes fade {
            0% {
                background-color: #b3b3b3;
            }


            100% {
                background-color: #ffffff;
            }
        }

        @keyframes fadeIn {
            from {
                opacity: 0;
                transform: scale(0.9);
            }

            to {
                opacity: 1;
                transform: scale(1);
            }
        }



        .dropdown-menu {
            display: none;
            list-style-type: none;
            padding-left: 5px;
            font-size: 25px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }

        li:before {
            content: "";
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
            background-image: url('Gearlogo.png'); /* Replace 'path/to/folder-icon.png' with the actual path to your folder icon image file */
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 21px 21px; /*Adjust the size of the icon as needed */
            width: 26px; /* Adjust the width of the icon as needed */
            height: 26px; /* Adjust the height of the icon as needed */
            margin-right: 5px; /* Adjust the spacing between the icon and the text as needed */
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

        .dropdown {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding-left: 0;
            font-size: 25px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }

            .dropdown:before {
                content: "";
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align: middle;
                background-image: url('foldericon.png'); /* Replace 'path/to/folder-icon.png' with the actual path to your folder icon image file */
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: 26px 26px; /*Adjust the size of the icon as needed */
                width: 26px; /* Adjust the width of the icon as needed */
                height: 26px; /* Adjust the height of the icon as needed */
                margin-right: 5px; /* Adjust the spacing between the icon and the text as needed */
                margin-bottom: 5px;
            }

        .machinelist {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-color: blue;
            padding: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 100px;
            list-style-type: none;
            overflow-y: auto;
            max-height: 275px;
            max-width: 275px;
            margin: 1px;
            border-radius: 7px;
        }

        .foldertitle {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 20px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-color: blue;
            list-style-type: none;
            overflow-y: auto;
            max-height: 255px;
            max-width: 295px;
            margin: 1px;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 7px;
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
            background-color: transparent; /* Set track background to transparent */
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background-color: #888;
            border-radius: 6px;
        }

        /* Firefox */
        scrollbar-width: thin;
        scrollbar-color: #888 transparent; /* Set thumb background to transparent */
        /* Internet Explorer and Edge */
        -ms-overflow-style: none; /* Hide the scrollbar */
        scrollbar-width: thin;
        scrollbar-color: #888 transparent; /* Set thumb background to transparent */
        body {
            margin: 1px;
            padding: 2px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            min-height: 10vh;
            background: #f7f7f7;
            border: 3px solid black;
            border-radius: 15px;
        }

        .container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            width: 100%;
            height: 98vh;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            border-radius: 10px;
            overflow: auto;
            margin: 1px;
        }

        .left-section {
            width: 20%;
            padding: 0px 3px;
            margin-right: 1px;
        }

            .left-section h2 {
                border: 1px solid #000;
                border-radius: 10px;
                text-align: center;
                margin: 3px 0px;
            }

            .left-section .new-section {
                border: 1px solid #000;
                border-radius: 7px;
                height: 460px;
            }

        .new-section {
            /* Your existing CSS properties... */
            /* Adding CSS from your provided code */
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-color: blue;
            padding: 25px;
            padding-bottom: 100px;
            list-style-type: none;
            overflow-y: auto;
            max-height: 275px;
            max-width: 275px;
            margin: 1px;
            border-radius: 7px;
            padding-top: 3px;
            padding-right: 75px;
        }

        ul {
            padding-left: 1px;
            margin-left: -12px;
        }

        .right-section-wrapper {
            width: 79.99%;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            border-radius: 10px;
            flex-direction: column;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding: 1px 1px;
            margin-left: 1px;
        }

        .header-section {
            padding: 0px 3px;
        }

            .header-section h2 {
                border: 1px solid #000;
                border-radius: 10px;
                padding: 1px;
                text-align: center;
                margin: 3px 0px;
            }

        .operator-section {
            padding: 0px 3px;
            margin-top: 1px;
            text-align: left;
        }

            .operator-section h2 {
                border: 1px solid #000;
                border-radius: 10px;
                padding: 7px;
                margin-top: 3px;
                margin-bottom: 3px;
                padding-left: 15px;
            }

        .right-section {
            flex-direction: column;
            height: calc(100% - 101px); /* 90px is roughly the height of the header-section, adjust if needed */
        }

        .top-section, .bottom-section {
            width: 99%;
            padding: 0px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            border-radius: 10px;
            margin: 3px 5px;
        }

        .top-section {
            height: 33.33%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .rectangle-container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: space-between;
            height: 100%;
            width: 30%;
        }

        .rectangle-large, .rectangle-small {
            background: grey;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            border-radius: 10px;
            margin: 10px;
        }

        .rectangle-large {
            height: 92%;
            width: 30%
        }

        .rectangle-small {
            height: 45%;
        }

        .rectangle-large h3 {
            border: none;
            padding: 35px;
            text-align: left;
            margin-top: 3px;
            margin-bottom: 3px;
        }

        .bottom-section {
            height: 66.67%;
            padding-bottom: 6px;
            margin-top: 3px;
        }

        .gauge {
            width: 30%;
            height: 60%;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            border-radius: 10px;
            margin: 20px;
        }


        /* Rest of your CSS from the provided code... */





        #machineinfo {
            margin-top: -52px;
            padding: 506px;
        }


        @keyframes fade {
            0% {
                background-color: #b3b3b3;
            }


            100% {
                background-color: #ffffff;
            }
        }

        @keyframes fadeIn {
            from {
                opacity: 0;
                transform: scale(0.9);
            }

            to {
                opacity: 1;
                transform: scale(1);
            }
        }



        .dropdown-menu {
            display: none;
            list-style-type: none;
            padding-left: 5px;
            font-size: 25px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }

        li:before {
            content: "";
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
            background-image: url('Gearlogo.png'); /* Replace 'path/to/folder-icon.png' with the actual path to your folder icon image file */
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 21px 21px; /*Adjust the size of the icon as needed */
            width: 26px; /* Adjust the width of the icon as needed */
            height: 26px; /* Adjust the height of the icon as needed */
            margin-right: 5px; /* Adjust the spacing between the icon and the text as needed */
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

        .dropdown {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding-left: 0;
            font-size: 25px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }

            .dropdown:before {
                content: "";
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align: middle;
                background-image: url('foldericon.png'); /* Replace 'path/to/folder-icon.png' with the actual path to your folder icon image file */
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: 26px 26px; /*Adjust the size of the icon as needed */
                width: 26px; /* Adjust the width of the icon as needed */
                height: 26px; /* Adjust the height of the icon as needed */
                margin-right: 5px; /* Adjust the spacing between the icon and the text as needed */
                margin-bottom: 5px;
            }

        .machinelist {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-color: blue;
            padding: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 100px;
            list-style-type: none;
            overflow-y: auto;
            max-height: 275px;
            max-width: 275px;
            margin: 1px;
            border-radius: 7px;
        }

        .foldertitle {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 20px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-color: blue;
            list-style-type: none;
            overflow-y: auto;
            max-height: 255px;
            max-width: 295px;
            margin: 1px;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 7px;
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
            background-color: transparent; /* Set track background to transparent */
        }

        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background-color: #888;
            border-radius: 6px;
        }

        /* Firefox */
        scrollbar-width: thin;
        scrollbar-color: #888 transparent; /* Set thumb background to transparent */
        /* Internet Explorer and Edge */
        -ms-overflow-style: none; /* Hide the scrollbar */
        scrollbar-width: thin;
        scrollbar-color: #888 transparent; /* Set thumb background to transparent */

        .right-section-wrapper.fullscreen {
            width: 100%;
        }



    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="left-section">
            <h2>CNC MACHINE LIST</h2>
            <div class="new-section">
                <ul>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" onclick="toggleDropdown(this)">A20</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><span href="#">01-CITIZEN-51</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-CITIZEN-52</span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" onclick="toggleDropdown(this)">HAAS</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><span href="#">01-HAAS-01</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-HAAS-02</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-HAAS-03</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-HAAS-04</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-HAAS-05</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-HAAS-06</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-HAAS-07</span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" onclick="toggleDropdown(this)">L20</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><span href="#">01-CITIZEN-01</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-CITIZEN-02</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-CITIZEN-03</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-CITIZEN-04</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-CITIZEN-05</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-CITIZEN-06</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-CITIZEN-07</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-CITIZEN-08</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-CITIZEN-09</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-CITIZEN-10</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-CITIZEN-11</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-CITIZEN-12</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-CITIZEN-13</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-CITIZEN-14</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-CITIZEN-15</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-CITIZEN-16</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-CITIZEN-17</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-CITIZEN-18</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-CITIZEN-19</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-CITIZEN-20</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-CITIZEN-21</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-CITIZEN-22</span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" onclick="toggleDropdown(this)">M20</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><span href="#">01-CITIZENM-05</span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <span class="dropdown-toggle" onclick="toggleDropdown(this)">M32</span>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><span href="#">01-CITIZENM-01</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-CITIZENM-02</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-CITIZENM-03</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-CITIZENM-04</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-CITIZENM-05</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-CITIZENM-06</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-CITIZENM-07</span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" onclick="toggleDropdown(this)">ROBODRILL</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><span href="#">ROBODRILL-03</span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" onclick="toggleDropdown(this)">ROLLOMATIC</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><span href="#">01-ROLLOMAT-01</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-ROLLOMAT-02</span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" onclick="toggleDropdown(this)">TORNOS</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><span href="#">01-TORNOS-01</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-TORNOS-02</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-TORNOS-03</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-TORNOS-04</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-TORNOS-05</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-TORNOS-06</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-TORNOS-07</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-TORNOS-08</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-TORNOS-09</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-TORNOS-10</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-TORNOS-11</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-TORNOS-12</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-TORNOS-13</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-TORNOS-14</span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" onclick="toggleDropdown(this)">TSUGAMI</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><span href="#">01-TSUGAMI-01</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-TSUGAMI-02</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-TSUGAMI-03</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-TSUGAMI-04</span></li>
                            <li><span href="#">01-TSUGAMI-05</span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="right-section-wrapper">

            <div class="header-section">
                <button id="fullscreen-button">Toggle Fullscreen</button>

                <h2>JOB AND CNC INFO</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="operator-section">
                <h2>Operator:</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="right-section">
                <div class="top-section">
                    <div class="rectangle-large">
                        <h3>Machine Status:</h3>
                        <h3>Mode:</h3>
                        <h3>Part Counter:</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="gauge">
                        <!-- Gauge meter will go here -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="rectangle-container">
                        <div class="rectangle-small"></div>
                        <div class="rectangle-small"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="bottom-section">
                    <!-- You can add content here -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

StyleSheet1.css

```
body {
    animation: fadeIn 0.5s ease-in forwards;
    animation: fade 0.35s ease-in-out forwards;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px grey;
}





@keyframes fade{
    0% {
        background-color: #b3b3b3;
    }
    
    
    100% {
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(0.9);
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}



.dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

li:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-image: url('Gearlogo.png'); /* Replace 'path/to/folder-icon.png' with the actual path to your folder icon image file */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 21px 21px; /*Adjust the size of the icon as needed */
    width: 26px; /* Adjust the width of the icon as needed */
    height: 26px; /* Adjust the height of the icon as needed */
    margin-right: 5px; /* Adjust the spacing between the icon and the text as needed */
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.dropdown {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}

    .dropdown:before {
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        background-image: url('foldericon.png'); /* Replace 'path/to/folder-icon.png' with the actual path to your folder icon image file */
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 26px 26px;/*Adjust the size of the icon as needed */
        width: 26px; /* Adjust the width of the icon as needed */
        height: 26px; /* Adjust the height of the icon as needed */
        margin-right: 5px; /* Adjust the spacing between the icon and the text as needed */
        margin-bottom:5px;
     
    }
    
.machinelist {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-color: blue;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 275px;
    max-width:275px;
    margin: 1px;
    border-radius:7px;
}

.foldertitle {
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-color: blue;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 255px;
    max-width: 295px;
    margin: 1px;
    border-radius:10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 7px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: transparent; /* Set track background to transparent */
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #888;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

/* Firefox */
scrollbar-width: thin;
scrollbar-color: #888 transparent; /* Set thumb background to transparent */
/* Internet Explorer and Edge */
-ms-overflow-style: none; /* Hide the scrollbar */
scrollbar-width: thin;
scrollbar-color: #888 transparent; /* Set thumb background to transparent */

body {
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 10vh;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    height: 98vh;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 1px;
}

.left-section {
    width: 20%;
    padding: 0px 3px;
    margin-right: 1px;
}

    .left-section h2 {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-radius: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 3px 0px;
    }

    .left-section .new-section {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-radius: 7px;
        height: 460px;
    }

.new-section {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-color: blue;
    padding: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 275px;
    max-width: 275px;
    margin: 1px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-right: 75px;
}

ul {
    padding-left: 1px;
    margin-left: -12px;
}

.right-section-wrapper {
    width: 79.99%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 1px 1px;
    margin-left: 1px;
}

.header-section {
    padding: 0px 3px;
}

    .header-section h2 {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 1px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 3px 0px;
    }

.operator-section {
    padding: 0px 3px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    text-align: left;
}

    .operator-section h2 {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 7px;
        margin-top: 3px;
        margin-bottom: 3px;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

.right-section {
    flex-direction: column;
    height: calc(100% - 101px); 
}

.top-section, .bottom-section {
    width: 99%;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 3px 5px;
}

.top-section {
    height: 33.33%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.rectangle-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 100%;
    width: 30%;
}

.rectangle-large, .rectangle-small {
    background: grey;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.rectangle-large {
    height: 92%;
    width: 30%
}

.rectangle-small {
    height: 45%;
}

.rectangle-large h3 {
    border: none;
    padding: 35px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.bottom-section {
    height: 66.67%;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}

.gauge {
    width: 30%;
    height: 60%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 20px;
}






#machineinfo {
    margin-top: -52px;
    padding: 506px;
}


@keyframes fade {
    0% {
        background-color: #b3b3b3;
    }


    100% {
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(0.9);
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}



.dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

li:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-image: url('Gearlogo.png'); /* Replace 'path/to/folder-icon.png' with the actual path to your folder icon image file */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 21px 21px; /*Adjust the size of the icon as needed */
    width: 26px; /* Adjust the width of the icon as needed */
    height: 26px; /* Adjust the height of the icon as needed */
    margin-right: 5px; /* Adjust the spacing between the icon and the text as needed */
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.dropdown {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

    .dropdown:before {
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        background-image: url('foldericon.png'); /* Replace 'path/to/folder-icon.png' with the actual path to your folder icon image file */
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 26px 26px; /*Adjust the size of the icon as needed */
        width: 26px; /* Adjust the width of the icon as needed */
        height: 26px; /* Adjust the height of the icon as needed */
        margin-right: 5px; /* Adjust the spacing between the icon and the text as needed */
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

.machinelist {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-color: blue;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 275px;
    max-width: 275px;
    margin: 1px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

.foldertitle {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-color: blue;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 255px;
    max-width: 295px;
    margin: 1px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Where's the button in your code please?

Comment: I updated the new code with the button and my attempt to do the fullscreen. Im tryna get an animation like enlargement and reduction without using the fullscreen API I just want the right-section-wrapper to overlap everything when the button is pressed

Comment: I also know I put the same CSS that is in the CSS file that is in the <style> html file For some reason it wouldnt work with just one even though its the same code.